# Stuck at sequential test during Python 3.7 installation on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

During installation, every time I try to run

```
make -j 4
```

it always stuck at

> 0:19:16 load avg: 0.95 [129/416] test_exception_variation

> 0:19:17 load avg: 0.96 [130/416] test_extcall

> 0:19:17 load avg: 0.96 [131/416] test_faulthandler

the longest I have waited is one night- for reference, I followed the tutorial from this website
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/#installing-python-37-on-debian

any help with this problem is appreciated

Comment: have you tried `make` without the j?

Comment: yeah I did...same outcome

Comment: did you solve it? I am stuck here too...

Comment: May be related https://bugs.python.org/issue38965

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions

make profile-gen-stamp; ./python -m test.regrtest --pgo -j8; make build_all_merge_profile; touch profile-run-stamp; make
```

For me it stuck on 415/416 test...
I dont know hos pass it :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue38965) "test_stack_overflow (test.test_faulthandler.FaultHandlerTests) is stuck with GCC10", I'd suggest to apply [this patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/17467/files) to `Modules/faulthandler.c` and run `make` again.

Tested on Devuan 4 (Debian 11)

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you faced with different python versions - use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), just install and u can easily do

```
pyenv install 3.7
pyenv shell 3.7
```